# Problem with engine starting up and dying right away

Tags: engine, honda, civic

I bought Honda Civic 2013 LX which had an issue with the original key. I drove with valet key and drove it about 60 miles. After that it's dead. I thought it's an original key issue which I have had programmed. Now at least it starts, but it dies right away. I sent it to the dealer and was recommended to change the fuel pump. It has been changed, but still has the issue. Engine starts and dies right away. Any one have clue what is that issue?

Comment: Is there a security light which came on? Sounds like (since you had to program the key) that there is a security interrupt which is killing the engine right after start-up.